# Css issue with top margin

Tags: css

I had created  the following divs and its definition.

```
<div class="serach-container">
  <div class="search-keys-container">
    <div class="search-type"> </div>
    <div class="basic-search-keys-container"> </div>
    <div class="advance-search-keys-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-result-container"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.search-type{
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
    margin:5px 10px;
    background-color:#4000A0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuthalasseril/cBrhX/2/)

But unfortunately the top-margin of class **search type** goes upwards. I tried by adjusting the margins so and so. But no result is found. Without margins it is ok. But I want the margins.

edit:

I dont know why top-margin is not working. Anyway an alternative solution is put another div say **error-correct** before the **search-type** div ie

```
<div class="serach-container">
  <div class="search-keys-container">
     <div class="error-correct"></div>
     <div class="search-type">/div>
     <div class="basic-search-keys-container"></div>
     <div class="advance-search-keys-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-result-container">
  </div>
</div>

.search-type{
  height:20px;
  width:auto;
  margin:0px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color:#4000A0;
}
.error-correct{
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuthalasseril/fxDDZ/5/)
Thanks all my friends for your great help.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to fit search-type - div  contain in search-keys-container div. Now the top margin of search-type div goes upwards

Comment: As a first point, I think you are being very strict with all those fixed heights and widths. Do you have any image of the result that do you expect?

Comment: can u wait a minute ?i will upload the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/cBrhX/7/)**

Try change that class like here:

```
.search-type{
height:50px;
width:90%;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: oh it works.....thanks @Riccardo thanks my god and also for all good peoples who helped me with quick replies

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
.search-type{
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
    margin:5px 10px 0 10px;
    background-color:#4000A0;
}
```

That makes it come down and still keeps your margins.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you are being a little bit too strict in your size definitions...
But to solve your problem, you should do this:

```
.search-result-container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.search-type{
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color:#4000A0;
}
```

To me, this looks like a bug or something, as margin isn't being applied against the parent, but the body tag.

Also, you have a minor typo in the first container `serach`

Comment: It also works thanks @juan for your reply. I dont know whats wrong with my rules...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding:0.01px` to `.search-keys-container`. It won't have any visual effect, but it will cause margins to not collapse like this.